# How to clear Memory warning in iOS

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

```
 NSString *strcustomerph=nil;
 if(condition)
 strcustomerph=@“…..”;
```

Getting leak “value stored to strcustomerph” is never read

Even Im using ARC,

1.Why did i get memory leak ?

2.How to clear that leak ?

Thank you...

Comment: How did you determine that you are leaking memory? The error you are suggesting just indicates, that the you are creating a string called strcustomerph but are not using it.

Comment: @TheAppMentor Thanks for reply, I'm getting a blue line at this step, is this is not a memory leak ? How to remove that where I'm going wrong

Comment: That warning is just telling you that you have declared a variable and are not using it. Where do you plan to use the string strcustomerph ?

Comment: In the next line I'm setting it to label text, Actually my intention is if the condition satisfies then only i want to assign a value to the string, so Im assigning it to nil at start..

Comment: Please Post the entire method.

Comment: k Thx for ur suggestions, Finally i came to to know that there one more assignment to that string before  adding to label text.. thnx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *strcustomerph=nil;
if(condition)
strcustomerph=@“…..”;

strcustomerph=@"my phonenumber";
```

// here I'm adding to my label.So the leak is due to the value which i was assigned first not used any place..

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

open project

First you should check any dead store variable which is in use. 
Go to Product -> Analyze and try to remove unused variable, Dead Store, warning and issue.

Second 
Go to Product -> Profile (after building process done) ->choose leaks in profiling template -> Start recording and test your app with all scenario. check memory warning and leaks.